# Udev rule not executing on usb insertion, should run script in background

Tags: bash, usb, scripts, udev

i wrote a udev rule and placed it in /etc/udev/rules/90-wifi.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="usb", RUN+="sh /usr/local/bin/setup_wifi_wrapper.sh"
```

It should run on every inserted usb device.

It should start the script /usr/local/bin/setup_wifi_wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/start_wifi.sh & disown
```

And that should start /usr/local/bin/start_wifi.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo systemctl start hostapd
sudo ifup br0
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
touch /home/user/started
```

But it does not...
The scripts are all executable and I can start them from command line and they do what they are supposed to do.
I tried having them in differente locations, started in the home folder moved them to usr/local/bin. Made the wrapper with disown for background processes but still no results. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `udev` man page for `RUN`:

> Execute an external program specified as the assigned value. If no absolute path is given, the program is expected to live in `/lib/udev`; otherwise, the absolute path must be specified.

`sh` is not in `/lib/udev`.

Furthermore, by beginning with `sh` the script is run by the Sh interpreter.  However, from the command line likely no interpreter was given, so the `#!/bin/bash` line would be used to select Bash.

The `disown` is Bash specific.  Therefore just remove the leading `sh` from this part of the rule:

```
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/setup_wifi_wrapper.sh"
```

Comment: Thank you, but sadly after changing the run part. The script is still not executed

Comment: Run `sudo udevadm control -R` to reload the rules and try again.  Does only the `touch` work, or does nothing happen at all?  Is there a specific USB device you want to match?

Comment: Still to no avail, i did use the reload before already. And no i would be happy with any usb device. I don't really care which one it is. Therefore it should be fairly generalized. But even with a more specilized ATTR() the rule does not trigger

Comment: I tried to simplifiy the rule. So I only have a touch in the wrapper script. But this is not executed as well. Therefore it seems, that the problem is, that the rule is never invoked

Comment: You solution actually worked... The problem was a minor typo on my side to get it completly working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

change the udev-rule

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/setup_wifi_wrapper.sh"
```

I would avoid the RUN+ Key.

And your the skript

```
 #!/bin/sh
/bin/sleep 10 
systemctl start hostapd &&
ifup br0 &&
systemctl restart dnsmasq &&
touch /home/user/started
```

The sequence only work if every command is successful.